Is this the appropriate to post a request for arxiv reference query, or is there another site I should use?
I have found a solution to a big research problem that I want to post on arxiv.  Unfortunately, due to mental illness, I haven't worked in years and have no connections in any mathematical community.
Would it be appropriate to post, maybe as an answer by me to a question I posted, a proof that I have almost finished (I'm still putting the finishing touches on it and should be done with it within one week) that e + pi is irrational?  My goal is to impress an established mathematician enough that the person would agree to be a reference for me so I could post my other paper on arxiv.
Thanks for any feedback and thoughts....

Unfortunately, announcements of original work are not allowed, and such a question would be quickly closed.

On [academia.se]: How to find an arXiv endorser

@MartinSleziak I had a look through that question (and others on academia.SE) just in case I thought they might be immediately useful to the OP, and most of the advice is aimed at younger academics or people adjacent to academia (eg Do you personally know any other researchers in the endorsement domain? Consider in particular former colleagues, former advisors,... or If you are a registered student in a recognized university or institute, you can register in arXiv with your school email address,... )

No, Philip, no. Absolutely not.

Claiming $e+\pi$ is irrational is a huge piece of news if true. I can only point to the advice in this answer https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/18570/8881 and the others there, in order than you are able to appreciate the position you are in.
As Andy said in the comments, posting proofs, announcements of proofs, claims of resolutions etc of famous open problems are off-topic for MathOverflow. Such posts are closed quickly.
Best of luck with your situation, and your maths explorations. You can still have fun even when not tackling famous problems, and your worth isn't tied to this proof being correct.

For context to the OP, here is a recent paper that managed to make the first progress on an irrationality result for decades https://arxiv.org/pdf/2408.15403 It proves that no sum of integer multiples of $\pi^2$ and the number $1 - \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{4^2} - \frac{1}{5^2} + \frac{1}{7^2} - \frac{1}{8^2} + \cdots \approx 0.781302412896486296\ldots$ can be rational. It's over 200 pages long and written by some of the best people in the world in the area. And it's really quite delicate work, it turns out...

Well, thanks...the challenge is to find any open problem that some mathematicians will not claim is "too famous" to be solved without skepticism.  Some things about the internet math world are unhealthy for a lot of people, including some of the stereotypes.  Anyway, I know how to check my work, it'll just be a question of finding the right venue to share my work at.  Maybe I'd have to publish to a journal.

@PhilipJ.White See also the "on publishing proofs of famous open problems" section here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/dont-prematurely-obsess-on-a-single-big-problem-or-big-theory/ If your techniques can prove $e+\pi \not\in \mathbb{Q}$ then they can prove other results that are low-hanging fruit, and you will build a reputation for solid work. With this established you will be taken more seriously than arriving out of the blue and claiming the proof of a famous conjecture with no track record.
